# Why am I receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a one-line condition statement for setting variable's value inside `state` of a React Component.
Please see the extracted code below:

```
class ModuleInstance extends React.Component {
  // Initial module counter
  state = {
    assignments: this.props.assignments,
    params: [
      {single_assigment: this.props.assigments.length === 1 ? true : false}
    ],
  }
```

ModuleInstance receives `assignments` as a passed prop from its parent class, however when attempting to assign `single_assigment` it does not recognize the prop and throws `*TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*`.
Please keep in mind I'm quite new to Javascript development but if someone could explain what's wrong with this - I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Yes, it would appear `assignments` prop was not passed to your React component. Can you post the JSX as well?

Comment: Actually on second look - seems like you just a misspelling here: `{single_assigment: this.props.assigments.length === 1 ? true : false}` should be `{single_assigment: this.props.assignments.length === 1 ? true : false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have passed correct `this.props.assignments`, apply a falsey check on `this.props.assignments`, and yeah correct the typo.

```
class ModuleInstance extends React.Component {
  // Initial module counter
  state = {
    assignments: this.props.assignments,
    params: [
      { single_assigment: (this.props.assignments && this.props.assignments.length === 1) ? true : false }
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in the name assignments, you were missing the n after g

```
class ModuleInstance extends React.Component {
  // Initial module counter
  state = {
    assignments: this.props.assignments,
    params: [
      {single_assignment: this.props.assignments.length === 1 ? true : false}
    ],
  }
```